# what is c++ compiler version on my device

Tags: c++

in cmd I typed `g++ -v` which results the message :

> Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
>   Target: mingw32
>   Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/configure --build=mingw32 --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-threads --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-gnu-ld --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --enable-cxx-flags='-fno-function-sections -fno-data-sections -DWINPTHREAD_STATIC' --prefix=/mingw32tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw32tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm-1 --enable-sjlj-exceptions --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
>   Thread model: posix
>   gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm-1)

I want to know what is my c++ version? which one it is, c++11/c++14/c++17?

Comment: Your _compiler version_ is gcc-5.1.0. A compiler can support several different _language versions_, typically specified via optional compiler flags, e.g. for GCC `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14` and so on. GCC 5.1 is very old though ([released April 22, 2015](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html)), and probably only offers partial C++14 support (no C++17 support, and likely full C++11 support).

Comment: Please read the [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) and consider upgrading to [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/). **Your `g++` is obsolete**

Comment: by how I do set a language by default to run on (say c++14)

Comment: You just read the documentation about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) but you should **upgrade your GCC compiler**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though your compiler version is 5.1.0 (from the directory name in the path)

C++11, or C++14 or C++17 do not have to do with the version of your downloaded compiler. Any compiler should have all of the versions of the standard which the compiler has implemented included in its download (as Nicolas Dusart pointed out, GCC 5.1.0 has only up to C++14). So you can specify which language specification you want to compile with with the -std={c++11, c++14, c++17} flag.

For instance, if you want to compile code using Concepts (a c++20 feature) you would have to use:

g++ main.cpp -o hello_world -std=c++20

Comment: G++ 5.1 supports up to C++14. It lacks a lot of C++17 features and  obviously nothing from C++20. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support